# Oracle/SQL: Depth, relations of the hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I need your help about this matter;

```
Fiedl1_Id        Fiedl1      Fiedl2_Id      Fiedl2
2470             199T        2348              949T 
2470             199T        2349              699T 
2470             199T        2356              649T 
2470             199T        2379              399T 
2470             199T        2383              299T 
2470             199T        2470              199T
```

I want to to implement into my sql query a code to add to this output of a query, a new field Depth, its principle is as follows:

```
Fiedl1_Id   Fiedl1  Fiedl2_Id   Fiedl2  Depth
2470        199T    2348        949T    1
2470        199T    2348        949T    2
2470        199T    2348        949T    3
2470        199T    2348        949T    4
2470        199T    2348        949T    5
2470        199T    2349        699T    1
2470        199T    2349        699T    2
2470        199T    2349        699T    3
2470        199T    2349        699T    4
2470        199T    2356        649T    1
2470        199T    2356        649T    2
2470        199T    2356        649T    3
2470        199T    2379        399T    1
2470        199T    2379        399T    2
2470        199T    2383        299T    1
2470        199T    2470        199T    0
```

I had 6 recordings including a record that has the Fiedl1_Id = Fiedl2_Id ( 2470) this one must have a Depth = 0, for others; have 5 depths for the first value of Fiedl2(949T), 4 depths for (699T) and so on in descending order.

Comment: There isn't really a hierarchy. Why do you have 5 'depth' values for 2348, but only 1 for 2382 - are you really just applying a rank based on field2 ID or value (descending), rather an a real hierarchy?

Comment: There is no rigorous explanation of where the depth comes from, but I know what you want is this kind of syntax `connect by prior t1.rowid = t1.rowid
   and level <= depth
   and prior sys_guid() is not null`

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I have 5 different recordings from the one 199T which are the following:  949T, 699T, 649T, 399T, 299T.                                                       
This list is orderd by Fiedl2_Id asc (ordered in growth by the identifier Fiedl2_Id); I want the first value(949T) to be repeated 5 times(number of 5 different recordings excluding the 199T that have Fiedl1_Id=  Fiedl2_Id) with a different depth, then for the second value(699T) be repeated 4 times with a different depth, for 649T be repeated 3 times .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the desired output for the given input:

```
WITH t (fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2)
AS
(
SELECT '2470','199T','2348','949T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2470','199T','2349','699T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2470','199T','2356','649T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2470','199T','2379','399T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2470','199T','2383','299T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2470','199T','2470','199T' FROM DUAL
), t_rn (fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2,rn) 
AS
(
SELECT fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) FROM t ORDER BY fiedl2 ASC
), t_depth (fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2,fdepth)
AS
(
SELECT fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2,rn - 1 FROM t_rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT fiedl1_id,fiedl1,fiedl2_id,fiedl2,fdepth - 1 FROM t_depth WHERE fdepth - 1 > 0

)
SELECT * FROM t_depth order by fiedl2 DESC, fdepth ASC;

FIED FIED FIED FIED     FDEPTH
---- ---- ---- ---- ----------
2470 199T 2348 949T          1
2470 199T 2348 949T          2
2470 199T 2348 949T          3
2470 199T 2348 949T          4
2470 199T 2348 949T          5
2470 199T 2349 699T          1
2470 199T 2349 699T          2
2470 199T 2349 699T          3
2470 199T 2349 699T          4
2470 199T 2356 649T          1
2470 199T 2356 649T          2
2470 199T 2356 649T          3
2470 199T 2379 399T          1
2470 199T 2379 399T          2
2470 199T 2383 299T          1
2470 199T 2470 199T          0
```

Comment: thank you very much that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Great to hear that.